# How did the Vulgar Latin 'parabola' evolve to mean 'word'?

Tags: etymology, latin

> [parable (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=parable&allowed_in_frame=0)   
>       mid-13c., parabol, modern form from early 14c., "saying or story in which something is expressed in terms of something else,"
>   from Old French parable "parable, parabolic style in writing" (13c.),
>   from Latin parabola "comparison,"
>   from Greek parabole "a comparison, parable," literally "a throwing beside," hence "a juxtaposition," from ***para-* "alongside"** (see [para-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=para-&allowed_in_frame=0) (1)) + ***bole* "a throwing, casting, beam, ray,"** related to ballein "to throw" (see [ballistics](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ballistics&allowed_in_frame=0)).
>
> Replaced Old English *bispell*. **In Vulgar Latin, *parabola* took on the meaning "word,"** hence Italian *parlare*, French *parler* "to speak" (see [parley](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=parley&allowed_in_frame=0) (n.)).

To connect word to the syntagma ***para-*** + ***bole***, I guessed the sad possibility that an illterate may just  recklessly **throw** or **cast** words **alongside** each other. But my guess appears wrong, because *parabola* had already evolved to mean 'comparison'. My 2nd guess is that words can be used for comparison, but this connection seems too faint. Maybe I erred again.

So would someone please explain? 
 I heed the Etymological Fallacy. But what are some right ways of interpreting the etymology, to make it feel reasonable and intuitive?

Comment: If you can read French: [wiktionary](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/parole#.C3.89tymologie) and [cnrtl](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/parole) entries both point at a calque from Hebrew "pārehāl" (?). Etymology is not always semantic anyway.

Comment: It seems clear to me that the sequence is "parable" -> "story" -> "words".

Comment: My amateur interpretation for this etimology said to me that a parabole is a non right movement, it is a curved one. This make sense for any use of not literal language.

Comment: You will find here http://english.stackexchange.com/q/175756/73094 what the rhetoric parable has in common with the mathematical parabola.

Answer (score 2):

There is a parallel double-borrowing from Greek with **amphibolum**.(my emphasis)

> Amphibolia (Cic), **amphibolum**, id. quod,
>   Amphibologia   *....An ambiguity, an equivocation; when a sentence may be construed two ways*
>   citing Terence and Quintillian. (Ainsworth, main thesaurus.)

Classical borrowing from Greek, rhetorical terms.
In late Latin this word is given in Ainsworth 'Voces' dialects, late usage.

> Amphibalum =**amphibolum** a loose garment, enveloping the body from
>   every side *Voss*.

For the physical meanings of *parabola* or *amphibolum* the throwing is physically up/against or around.
 But in rhetoric it is not so much the words, as the meanings that are thrown up against each other, or entangled with each other.
The Greek rhetorical use is certainly first century.

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?

Comment: @Colin Fine. It seems to me an analogous process. ραραβολα **:** parable (lit) parole (meton) **::** Αμφιβολή **:** amphiboly (lit) amphibalum (a casting net/ a loose garment (meton).  In each case the metamorphosis takes place in medieval Latin.

Comment: @ColinFine To user 'Hugh' too: +1. Thanks. Your answer helps me understand how ***para- + bole*** evolved to mean  "saying or story in which something is expressed in terms of something else". However, did you explain how `parabola took on the meaning "word"? I'm still confused because the noun 'word' is straightforward; so nothing's thrown up or against each other.

Comment: Would you please respond in your answer, which is easier to read than comments?